# sequelize.sync({alter:true}) not working sometimes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

I try to alter my table structure using sequelize sync. But the table structure not get updated.

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
 var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.dbConnectionString);
 sequelize.sync({alter:true});
```

Note: I need data in the database. so, can't use **force:true**